# WKB approximation in two dimensions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, potential, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator

Does anybody know how to implement the WKB approximation for the two-dimensional Schrodinger equation with a harmonic oscillator potential:

$$\frac{1}{2}\Biggl[-\biggl(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\biggr)+x^2 + y^2 + 2xy\Biggr]\psi(x,y) = E\psi(x,y).$$

Comment: Physics.StackExchange is not a homework-help site.  If you have a question about a homework problem, or any problem of an educational nature, narrow it down to the specific concept that is giving you trouble and ask about that. You can find more [information about acceptable homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) on our meta site.

Comment: It's sometime since you asked this but notice the potential term is $x^2 + 2 xy + y^2 = r^2$. Presumably you then have to write $\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}$ in terms of plane polar co-ordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Rotate the coordinate system $45^{\circ}$:

$$x_{\pm}~:=~\frac{x\pm y}{\sqrt{2}}.\tag{1}$$

Then the [TISE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) separates into (1D harmonic oscillator) $\times$  (1D free particle):
$$ \left(-\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_+^2}   +x_+^2-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_-^2}\right)\psi(x_+,x_-) ~=~E\psi(x_+,x_-),\tag{2} $$
which can be solved exactly. No need for WKB approximations.